# Are virtuous humans reborn as Devas and sinful humans reborn as Demons?

Tags: reincarnation, deva, virtue

Or is it more complicated than that? i.e random?

Answer (score 2):

The Buddha connects rebirth with morality. Right view and shining morality leads to the heavens. Wrong view and hellish conduct leads to the hells.

It is a little bit difficult to translate the Buddhist term "hell-dweller" as "demon." They are not quite the same as "demons" which we know from Judeo-Christian folklore.

Comment: my impression is 'asura' are demons

Answer (score 2):

While it's certainly a bit more complicated that that, it definitely doesn't happen randomly. Refer to the [31 Planes of Existence](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html). Notice the 3rd column on each table for each realm lists the various causes that lead to rebirth into that particular realm. It also provided backup sutta references.

Comment: the chart says that being reborn as a Deva is much more common than being reborn as a human again, why is that besides humans being a balance of pleasure and suffering?

Comment: @Orionixe, I already checked the web page and it only says "Rebirth a a human being is extraordinary rare", but nowhere does it say that "being reborn as a Deva is much more common than being reborn as a human again".

Comment: I would be reborn as a Deva if I perform 10 wholesome actions and express virtue and generosity? According to the chart.

Comment: not just "express", but actual development of virtues and generosity as specified in AN 10.177 on the same chart. It's that simple. But then again, just because something is simple doesn't mean it's easy.

Answer (score 1):

The suttas describe beings reappearing in different realms, according to their actions, ie kamma. Skillful actions are said to lead to rebirth in a "higher" realm, and vice versa.

Answer (score -3):

In the Pali scriptures there are various teachings on 'rebirth', which give the impression The Buddha was inconsistent or, otherwise, scriptures were added after the Buddha passed away.

For example, the following stock phrase indicates two general 'rebirths' of 'heaven' & 'hell':

> When my concentrated mind was thus purified, bright, unblemished, rid
> of imperfection, malleable, wieldy, steady, and attained to
> imperturbability, I directed it to knowledge of the passing away and
> reappearance of beings. With the divine eye, which is purified and
> surpasses the human, I saw beings passing away and reappearing,
> inferior and superior, fair and ugly, fortunate and unfortunate. I
> understood how beings pass on according to their actions thus: ‘These
> worthy beings who were ill conducted in body, speech, and mind,
> revilers of noble ones, wrong in their views, giving effect to wrong
> view in their actions, on the dissolution of the body, after death,
> have reappeared in a state of deprivation, in a bad destination, in
> perdition, even in **hell**; but these worthy beings who were well
> conducted in body, speech, and mind, not revilers of noble ones, right
> in their views, giving effect to right view in their actions, on the
> dissolution of the body, after death, have reappeared in a good
> destination, even in the **heavenly** world.’ Thus with the divine eye,
> which is purified and surpasses the human, I saw beings passing away
> and reappearing, inferior and superior, fair and ugly, fortunate and
> unfortunate, and I understood how beings pass on according to their
> actions.
>
> [MN 4](https://suttacentral.net/mn4/en/bodhi)

Yet the following teaching indicates five potential 'rebirths':

> And what is the diversity in kamma? There is kamma to be experienced
> in **hell**, kamma to be experienced in the realm of common **animals**, kamma
> to be experienced in the realm of the hungry shades [**ghosts**], kamma to be
> experienced in the **human** world, kamma to be experienced in the world
> of the **devas**. This is called the diversity in kamma.
>
> [AN 6.63](https://suttacentral.net/an6.63/en/thanissaro)

The following teaching indicates six potential 'rebirths', which includes 'demons':

> Unfree from the bonds of Māra They swell the ranks of **hell**, Existence
> in the **animal** realm, Asura-**demons** and the sphere of **ghosts**.
>
> [Iti 93](https://suttacentral.net/iti93/en/ireland)

The following teaching indicates the virtuous can have 'rebirth' in 'hell' and unvirtuous can have 'rebirth' in 'heaven':

> the evil-doer who goes to **hell** (or some other low state of birth)
>
> the evil-doer who goes to **heaven**
>
> the good man who goes to **heaven**, and
>
> the good man who goes to **hell** (or other low birth).
>
> [MN 136](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.136.nymo.html)

The following teaching indicates all of the virtuous (puthujjana) who have not gained enlightenment will be 'reborn' in 'hell':

> … the sentient beings who die as humans and are reborn as humans are few, while those who die as humans and are reborn in **hell** are many …
>
> Why is that? It’s because they haven’t seen the four noble truths.
>
> [SN 56.102](https://suttacentral.net/sn56.102/en/sujato?layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

Comment: I marked your answer down because it doesn't answer the question. You seem more interested in questioning the idea of rebirth in the suttas, a familiar agenda in your case.

Comment: sorry but my answer is on topic.  ignorance is free to make bad kamma

Comment: No, your answer is an off-topic rant about the "inconsistency" of rebirth teachings on the suttas.